# What is the family of Fedora OS?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, fedora

Which OS family does Fedora belongs?

1. [Fedora Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28Linux_distribution%29) : **Unix-Like**.
2. [Fedora Project Page](http://fedoraproject.org/en/features/) : **Linux-based**.

*Question -* Difference between **Unix-Like** and **Linux-Based**?

> P.S  : A neophyte in Unix vs Linux Architecture.

Comment: Fedora is Linux. Linux is Unix-like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Unix like* - having a similar interface like unix.

*Linux based* - derived from the linux original implementation.

Linux is an operating system kernel that is designed `like Unix's` kernel.

Fedora is `Linux based` operating system, this linux based operating system kernel designed `like unix`.